# Is it possible to replicate cat(1) with POSIX sh(1)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, posix, sh

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html

POSIX `sh(1)` is capable of various file descriptor operations (equivalent to `open(2)`, `close(2)` and `dup(2)`, *etc.*) as well as `read`-ing a single line from STDIN.

So I got an impression that we can replace `cat(1)` with a POSIX-compliant shell script, but I haven't come up with an actual implementation. Is it really possible, or, what function of `cat(1)` might be missing from `sh(1)`? (Forget about GNU extensions for now)

Don't ask me why I want to do that. As an intellectual quiz, maybe?

Comment: More of a question for http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cat` can copy any file to stdout; the file does not need to be a text file. It might include `NUL`s, for example, and a `NUL` cannot be represented in a `sh` string. So that would definitely be a feature of `cat` that would be very difficult, if not impossible, to implement. [Note 1]

Other than that, you should be able to wrap a `read` and `echo` inside a `while` loop, although there are some tricky issues. (Accurately reproducing a non-empty file which does not end in a newline, for example.)

But, technically, `echo` is no more part of `sh` than `cat` is; just like `cat`, it is a utility which might not be present (on a non-Posix system). In practice, environments without `echo` are about as likely as environments without `cat`; if you have `sh`, you have a reasonable expectation of finding the standard command line utilities.

---

#### Notes

1. The only option accepted by a minimal Posix-compatible `read` is `-r`. However, if we had the bash implementation of `read`, we could copy a file character by character, even though the `NUL` character will never actually appear in a shell variable:

   ```
   while IFS= read -d '' -rn1 char; do
     if [ -z "$char" ]; then printf '\0'; else printf '%s' "$char"; fi
   done < "$1" > "$2"
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   $ printf 'foo\0bar\n\nbye' |
   > while IFS= read -d '' -rn1 char; do
   >   if [ -z "$char" ]; then printf '\0'; else printf '%s' "$char"; fi
   > done |
   > hd
   00000000  66 6f 6f 00 62 61 72 0a  0a 62 79 65              |foo.bar..bye|
   0000000c
   ```

   The complete set of options to `read` in that invocation is carefully crafted to work around a variety of idiosyncracies in the bash implementation:

   - `IFS=` avoids trailing whitespace characters being removed from the result.
   - `-n1` causes one character to be read, up to the delimiter. Intuitively, `-N1` would be more natural, since `-N1` ignores the delimiter. However, `read` also strips `NUL` characters from the input. Since the intent is to store zero characters in `$char` if the next character is a `NUL`, we can avoid the problem by using `-n1` and setting the delimiter to `NUL`, which works because the delimiter check is done before the `NUL`s are stripped.
   - `-d ''` sets the line delimiter character to `NUL`. See above.
   - `-r` avoids having <kbd>\</kbd> being interpreted in the input stream; this is the only Posix-compatible option in the set.

   It should go without saying that the above is only of theoretical interest, or as an intellectual quiz as per the OP. In practice, a shell script should do no more than coordinate the work of external utilities, and the existence of Posix-compatible utilities such as `cat`, `dd`, `head` and `tail` should be sufficient for any file copying needs.

Comment: `cat () { while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < "$1"; }`

Comment: @nodakai: it's a huge difference, and that is why I lead with it. Do you feel I need to be more explicit?

Comment: @glen: that will miss any characters following the last newline.

Comment: It would've helped if you wrote "this is my solution, except, it is not a solution."

Comment: @nodakai: I rather deliberately did not provide a solution, but anyway I added more words. Arguably, the second paragraph should be a comment.

Comment: If you want line numbers -- i=0;while IFS= read -r line; do printf "%04d %s" ++i $line; done < "$1";

Comment: @nodakai: I'm still curious what aspect of this problem triggered your question... The loop provided by glenn jackman -- even with the required fix -- is hardly complicated, so there must be something fundamental which renders it a non-solution. If it's the NULs, then cool...

Comment: @glennjackman @rici Adding `case "$line" in; ?*) echo "$line";; esac;` seems to fix the problem of a line w/o EOL, but it isn't clear to me if `$line` should really be empty in the next iteration after the last line WITH EOL. Note: POSIX reads "EXIT STATUS 0 Successful completion. >0 End-of-file was detected or an error occurred."

Comment: @rici My motivation is along the line of: "when I port a shell script to Win32 or some extremely feature-limited jail environment, do I have to guarantee the availability of `cat(1)` (among others)?" If `sh(1)` were actually capable of something like Linux `sendfile(2)` and I were simply unaware of it, then it would have been ideal... But nobody pointed me to such a feature so far, so I come to believe it's really missing from `sh(1)`.  Perhaps I have to use something like busybox.

Comment: @nodakai: If your environment has `sh` (not guaranteed on Win32, I would think), then it will almost certainly have `cat`. Technically (perhaps I should add this to the answer), `sh` is not capable of emulating `cat`, or indeed doing any form of output, because `echo` almost none of the commands are guaranteed to be built-in; `echo` may well be external, and therefore absent. But that would make about as much sense as an environment without `cat`. I think you could legitimately complain about a jail environment missing either of those.

Comment: @nodakai: Your fix for files not ending with a newline doesn't work, since it will add a newline which was not previously present. `echo -n` is non-standard; `printf` is possible (and also Posix guaranteed) but see my previous comment.

Comment: @rici Points taken, the "solution" must not rely on `echo(1)` or `printf(1)` when `cat(1)` isn't guaranteed to be available. It's unfortunate an equivalent of `fputs(3)` was expelled from `sh(1)` when an equivalent of `fgets(3)` is still there, *just becuase* only the latter alters the execution environment and thus must be a built-in.

Comment: @nodakai: A close reading of POSIX shows that there is no such thing as a standard built-in. The standard leaves it open to the implementation to find a magical way for an external utility to alter the environment.  There are a handful of special utilities, which is as close as POSIX comes to the idea of "built-in", but `read` is not one of them.

Comment: @rici When the POSIX document of [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) states "RATIONALE The read utility historically has been a shell built-in. It was separated off into its own utility to take advantage of the richer description of functionality introduced by this volume of POSIX.1-2008." I understood it as: it isn't among [Special Built-in Utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14) embedded into the Shell Command Language *just because* of an editorial reason of the specification. Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @rici Anyways you're right in that when it isn't among Special Built-in Utilities, it isn't.

Comment: @glennjackman That also misses any characters between a NULL byte and a new line, as the expansion of `"$line"` will be truncated at the NULL byte. `printf 'foo\0bar\n' > tmp.txt; IFS= read -r line < tmp.txt; echo "$line"`.

Comment: Now I want to delete my comment, but I'll leave it for history.

Answer (score 1):

(This is essentially the same as @rici's answer, but with a concrete example of a file that cannot be displayed with `sh` alone.)

`cat` cannot be replicated using `sh` alone. This is because `sh` does not provide any method for moving bytes from one file to another that does not involve a shell parameter, and shell parameters cannot contain NULL bytes.

Here's a simple example:

```
printf 'foo\0bar\n' > tmp.txt  # Create a file containing a null byte
IFS= read -r line < tmp.txt    # Real that line into a variable.
echo "$line"                   # Only outputs "foo"
```

Comment: That still doesn't work; it cannot distinguish between a blank line and a null byte. Try with `printf 'foo\0bar\n\nbye'`.

Comment: Nope, still replaces the blank line with a null byte. From the shell's perspective, there is *no* difference between an empty string and a string containing a null byte, since every string is null-terminated.

Comment: I didn't say `read` would mishandle NULs, just that you can't tell from the resulting parameter if it did or not. `$'\0'` and `""` are indistinguishable to the shell; both contain zero characters before the first NUL encountered.

Comment: I put the bash solution and a demonstration that it works using your example as a note to my answer. Cheers.

Comment: Nice; I never got around to adding `-d` to the mix. So many pieces to get right!

Comment: Yeah, after I f*d around with it for a while, I remembered that I'd actually done this before. It's probably somewhere on SO.